# Displaying file names of an image

Tags: c#

So I want to display the file name of an image in a label in form 2, form 1 is where I'm going to select the picture and then it'll place it into form 2, but i want it to display the filename of the image that has been selected in the label called 'FileNameLabel' into form 2. This meaning the file location

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This should display the filename.

```
    if (SelectMedia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (SelectMedia.FilterIndex == 1)
        {
            PictureViewer picture = new PictureViewer();
            picture.SetPicture(SelectMedia.FileName);
            FileNameLabel.Text = SelectMedia.FileName;
            picture.Show();

        }
    }
```

Your SetPicture method takes the filename to put the picture into the picture box. 
That is the same filename that will get displayed in your FileNameLabel. 
If you are asking to display the full filepath then you need to do this.

```
            if (SelectMedia.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (SelectMedia.FilterIndex == 1)
                {
                    PictureViewer picture = new PictureViewer();
                    picture.SetPicture(SelectMedia.FileName);
                    FileInfo path = new FileInfo(SelectMedia.FileName);
                    FileNameLabel.Text = path;
                    picture.Show();
                }
            }
```

If those aren't what you are after explain a lot better about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thats what I did before, I added the FileNameLabel.Text = SelectMedia.FileName; but it just came up with "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Its updated! Btw thats the media form, the file name label is in picture form.. I want the file name to appear in the FileNameLabel in the picture form.. Would you like me to show you the picture form aswell?

Comment: Yes since you get the Filename from the picture itself. Show me the other one please.

Comment: That would only work when the save button is clicked. I want it to come up with the file name when the image is opened from form 1 and then placed in form 2

Comment: Where are you getting FileInfo from?

Comment: I just keep getting the squiddly red line

Comment: copy Fileinfo into your code then left click and click add file.io